# Eclipse TFS Plugin does not detect changes

Tags: eclipse, tfs

I'm working with Eclipse and Microsoft TFS Plugin

The problem I'm having is that whenever I make a change to a file (inside Eclipse) the plugin does not detect the changes and I have to force the detection with the "Detect Local Changes" button.

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance, Guillermo

Eclipse: Eclipse Kepler
OS: Mac OSX Yosemite

Comment: Server workspace or local workspace?  How did you import your project?  What options do you have in the Team context menu for a file, or for the project?  A screenshot of the Team context menu might help.

Comment: This has been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903125/eclipse-tfs-plugin-not-detecting-changes