# Eclipse TFS plugin not detecting changes

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse *Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)*, and have installed TFS plugin in it.

When I am making any changes to the code, the changed files not show up in **Included Changes** in **TFVC Pending Changes Tab**, all the changed files show up there only after restart of the eclipse or manually clicking on *Action -> Detect Local Changes*.

Anybody have solution to this problem, so that I dont have to restart eclipse or or manually clicking on *Action -> Detect Local Changes* and it detects it automatically.

Comment: Are you working on Server workspace or Local workspace? How did you import your project? Besides, did the changes made to files outside of Eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, please double check whether you are using **server workspaces** or **local workspaces**.

> - In a *server workspace*, TFS requires that you inform the server for    every change - to check out a file, rename, delete, etc.  This
>     allows    TFS to avoid scanning your disk for changes, which is
>     beneficial for    large repositories.  If you want to force a disk
>     scan with Team    Explorer Everywhere, because you may have made some
>     changes outside    of Eclipse, you can go to the Actions menu and
>     **select Detect Local  Changes**.
> - In a *local workspace*, TFS will examine your disk for changes every    time you look at the pending change status.  So all you have
>     to do is    run `tf status` or click refresh in the Pending Changes
>     View to see changes made to files outside of Eclipse.

According to your description, seems you are using serverworkspaces. If so suggest you switch to a Local workspace, in which case TFS will store a copy of your file in a hidden folder, so that it always knows what your workspace version looked like when TFS served it to you.

As how to judge you are working on server workspace or local workspace and edit workspaces, follow below steps:

1. In **Project Explorer** or **Package Explorer**, right-click an
   Eclipse project that is under version control, point to **Team**,
   and click **Manage Workspaces.**

[image]

2. **The Workspaces dialog** box appears. It shows you the list of your Team Foundation Server workspaces.
3. Then select the one you want to convert, click **Edit**; the **Edit Workspace dialog** box appears just as
       below screenshot:

[image]

***Note: Local workspaces are only supported for Team Foundation Server 2012 and above.***

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, this worked for me. I was using server workspace and now I have switched to local workspace